# Describing the bounds (upper and/or lower) sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

For ${(-1/2)^n}$, the sequence will be $\{-1/2, 1/4, -1/8, 1/16, ...\}$ and I determined the the lower and upper bounds to be -1/2 and 1/4, respectively, by plotting a couple of points. But Is there a way to determine the upper in this case in some other way? If it wasn't a power I would use a limit as n approaches infinity and try to solve it but not sure how to use limits here because I just get infinity in the power and not sure what to do with it.

Comment: if $|a|<1$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}a^n=0$. But that's irrelevant to the question since $-\frac{1}{2}<0$ and $\frac{1}{4}>0$ so $0$ is neither a lower or upper bound.

Comment: Not only are -1/2 and 1/4 lower and upper bound respectively, but they are the infimum and supremum of the sequence.
Have you tried induction to prove it is always less than the upper bound and greater than the lower bound?

Comment: I have not tried induction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the absolute values of the numbers in the sequence, we get a new sequence with the rule $(1/2)^n$.   Every number in the new sequence is $1/2$ of the previous number and we see that the terms of the sequence are  getting smaller and smaller. The upper bound is the first number or $1/2$ and the next largest number is $1/4$.

Going back to your rule $(-1/2)^n$: there will be negative and positive numbers.  $-1/2$ is negative so it can't be the upper bound. $1/4$ is larger than all the positive numbers after it, and will be larger than any of the negative numbers including $-1/2$.

The lower bound will be the smallest negative number, which is the negative number with the largest absolute value.  Since the number with the largest absolute value is negative, it will the lower bound. Therefore $-1/2$ is the lower bound.

Comment: I think I'll start using absolute values for alternating sequence, this actually helped me with another thing that I thought I knew.

Comment: I'm glad I helped, but I realize I used a slightly different sequence -(-1/2)^n, so that I told you about 1/2, -1/4,  1/8, -1/16 instead of -1/2, 1/4, -1/8, 1/16.  The argument would still work - I just had my signs backward.

Comment: I edited the answer to fix my careless mistakes.