# Lower bound of $a_n=1+(-3/4)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

I want to find the upper and lower bound of the following sequence

$$a_n=1+\left(\frac{-3}{4} \right)^n$$

For the upper bound, things are quite trivial since $\left(\frac{-3}{4} \right)^n<1$, hence $a_n\leq 2$. However, I'm getting a bit confused when it comes to the lower bound. I know that the sequence is not monotone, and therefore the first terms cannot give me a hint about what to expect.

I would appreciate if somebody could help me figure out this.

EDIT: Since we have been discussed about subsequences yet, I would prefer an answer without them.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want ANY lower bound ot the BEST lower bound ?

Comment: @Peter There is no specification about it, hence I guess any should work

Comment: This (mutatis mutandis) answers your question: [Describing the bounds (upper and/or lower) sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331994/describing-the-bounds-upper-and-or-lower-sequence).

Comment: @AnneBauval No, not really. I am sorry but I do not see how this could answer my question and therefore be a duplicate

Comment: I said "[mutatis mutandis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutatis_mutandis)". It shows you how to find the bounds for $(-1/2)^n.$ Those for $(-3/4)^n$ are analogous, and an obvious translation gives those for your sequence.

Comment: Is your sequence indexed by $n\ge 0$ or $n\ge 1$ (or something else)? That's important if you are looking for the *least* upper bound. For example, if $n\ge 0$, $2$ is not the least upper bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a_{2n} = 1 + \left(\frac{9}{16}\right)^n$ is descreasing and tends to $1$ so it stays above $1$.

$a_{2n+1} = 1 - \frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{9}{16}\right)^n$ is increasing. Its first term is $\frac{1}{4}$, so overall $$a_n \geq \frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt answer but I would prefer an answer without using subsequences...

Comment: Your "preference" is strange. Imo, this is the clearest possible answer. Anyway, it is a duplicate.

Comment: @AnneBauval We are not allowed to use subsequneces yet

Comment: You don't *have to* pronounce the word "subsequence". Simply say you split the set E of values of your sequence in two distinct parts A, B, and $\inf E=\min(\inf A,\inf B)=\min(1,1/4)=1/4.$ You cannot be forbidden (what an awful word from a math teacher!) to "use subsequences" since you can invent that notion without having being taught it. The only thing you can be forbidden is to use some theorem which you are not able to prove.